# Get notified when EditText changes in ListView

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` with multiple `EditText` views. I want to get notified when text in any if these `EditText` views changes, so that I can save it before the view is scrolled off screen. I first tried implementing `OnKeyListener`, but figured out that it does not always work for soft keyboards. I then implemented `TextWatcher`, but when writing the `afterTextChanged` method, I realised that it only tells you what text has changed, not which EditText it belongs to.

So is there any way to detect when text changes regardless of the input method, and also to know which object the text is changed in?

Comment: where you have implemented your textwather,you should implement it in your getview method of adapter and there you can get the position of the edittext

Comment: Thank you! I could not find any `setTextChangedListener`, on the object but realised that it is called `addText...`. Post as answer and I`ll accept as solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement a custom `ListAdapter` to achieve this. In your `getView` method, you implement the `TextWatcher`. Something like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

    }


    EditText et = v.findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    return v;

}
```